# How to control relay using SIM800 and Arduino Mega through SMS?

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm

For my project I need to control relays through SMS and now I can send SMS from my SIM800 module which is connected to Arduino Mega R3. But I tried several shapes for AT commands to receive SMS and parse it to check sender number and SMS text but every time I received a 2 digits number in serial monitor of Arduino,

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: In below page I found a code which can solve my problem with some modification but when I tried to compile it, there was an error which has displayed gt is not declared in this scope. and I could not find out what gt usage is

Comment: LINK: http://www.ayomaonline.com/iot/sim800-controlling-arduino-with-sms/

Comment: Replace every `&gt;` with `>` and it should work.

Comment: Probably something wrong with the website, since `&gt;` is the HTML entitie for `>`

Comment: thanks for your comment, I had changed the gt symbol with > and &lt with < there is not any error after modification but still not any response when SMS receive

Comment: Update your post with the code you have now.

Comment: and based on these modifications the code is pasted below:

Comment: } else if (lastLine.length() > 0) {
          if(nextLineIsMessage) {
            Serial.println(lastLine);
            if(lastLine.indexOf("LED ON") >= 0){
              ledStatus = 1;
            } else if(lastLine.indexOf("LED OFF") >= 0) {
              ledStatus = 0;
            }
            nextLineIsMessage = false;
          }
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(currentLine);  ++i ) {
         currentLine[i] = (char)0;
        }
        currentLineIndex = 0;
    } else

Comment: Since code was too long to update here so I had to paste some parts of it. for checking please paste complete code from above link then in void loop do necessary modifications by finding and replacing &gt; with > AND &lt; with <

Comment: with below code I could receive sms but still seeking a way to parse it

Comment: #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
// software serial #1: TX = digital pin 10, RX = digital pin 11
SoftwareSerial SIM800(10, 11);
void setup() 
{

SIM800.begin(19200);
Serial.begin(19200);
SIM800.write("AT+CMGF=1\r"); //set GSM to text mode
delay(1500);

SIM800.write("AT+CPMS=\"SM\"\r"); //Preferred SMS Message Storage
delay(1000);
while(0!=SIM800.write("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0\r\n")){
SIM800.write("AT+CMGR=1\n\r"); //list the first message from SIM Memory
SIM800.write("AT+CMGD=1\r");
}
while(1)
{
if(SIM800.available())
{

} 
}
}

void loop() 
{

}